# Placeholder text best practices for accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

Given following markup as an example:

```html
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" placeholder="foo@bar.baz" id="email" />

<label for="cc">Credit card</label>
<input type="input" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" id="cc" />
```

Will screen reader read something like "Email field, foo at bar dot com", "Credit card X X X X space X X X X space ..."? If yes, I guess that is not the best user experience and it is better to avoid using placeholders this way. Are there guidelines or examples of how to give user a short hint intended to aid the user with data entry in an easy to understand format that works for all users?

Answer (score 5):

Screen readers such as JAWS and NVDA do not read placeholder text, it's a visual addition only.

However, if you're providing important information visually (such as format for data entry) there is no reason you shouldn't be conveying this information to screen reader users as well. A good way to do this is with a screen reader only bit of text. Create a class using CSS which hides the text visually (off screen), and pop it into a span where you'd like it to be read out.

I've used the example of a Date of Birth below, as the format for entering a date can widely vary. Things like credit card numbers and email addresses are pretty standard and probably don't require hints.

```css
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  left: -99999px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<label for="DOB">
  DOB <span class="sr-only">Enter date in the format DD/MM/YYYY</span>
</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="DOB">
```

Comment: This has changed in JAWS 2019 which now reads placeholder text, and what's worse is it will read both the placeholder text and the aria-label, making for a redundant double reading of the text.  Per spec it should only read the placeholder if an aria-label is not present, but they don't follow the spec to the letter.

Comment: Worth noting that is HTML allows having more than one label for the same form element.
So it should be possible to create a separate label for screen readers.

Comment: It should be noted here as well - voiceover Safari, FF on mac m1 2021 reads both aria-label and placeholder as well.

Answer (score 1):

The placeholder text has to be seen as a purely decorative element. It may not be read by screenreaders.

In your examples, that's perfectly ok. Screenreader users perfectly know the format of an e-mail address, and do not want to ear "ex ex ex ex. ex ex ex ex. ex ex ex ex. ex ex ex ex." instead of "enter your credit card number" *(note that grouping four by four is impossible when your card number has 13 digits.)*

If you really have to give a hint, you have to insert it in the label:

More information on the W3C Webpage:

- [Placeholder Research](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/low-vision-a11y-tf/wiki/Placeholder_Research)
- [G89: Providing expected data format and example](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G89.html)

Answer (score 0):

Formatting hints are good for all users, whether visually impaired or not.  Having an example below the field and associated with the field using `aria-describedby` is how I usually do it.

```
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" id="email" aria-describedby="format"/>
<span id='format'>Format: foo@bar.baz</span>
```